# Optimise (indexing) query which have GROUP BY syntax

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT MIN(id) 
FROM mytable 
WHERE lastname IN('Smit','Lee') 
GROUP BY name
```

Here, for optimise this query, index needed (will be useful) column **lastname** right?
and column **name** also needed index? or only indexed lastname is enough?

Comment: you can index for three, first by `lastname`, then by `name` and last by `id`: RDBMS locate rows by lastname, group this rows by name and finally take the min id from the group. And table is untouched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the proposed indexes should help in your situation, however that depends a lot on the data you have and how costly certain operations are considered by the database engine, depending on if you have duplicates for id, which I suspect you don't and that's why it's called id, but if you do an 2-column index on `lastname, id` or `name, id` would also help. Ultimately the query optimizer will decide on the strategy to use to fetch data and that will certainly affect many things...
I propose you try the following and see which is faster

- index on `lastname` - likely
- index on `name` - a bit less likely
- index on `lastname, name` - most likely
- index on `name, lastname` - least likely

Again it really depends on the data but I marked each of those in the order in which I think they should help most for large amounts of data with unique id's, if your id's are not unique try combinations with indexes on id as well.

Comment: Yes, id's are unique, understood, I will be  use EXPLAIN and test variants, thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

The index on lastname will generally be useful for that query. Indexing name should not have an effect.

You can (and should) use EXPLAIN to see how MySQL will execute your query.

Answer (score 2):

A good rule to live by in programing is to never assume you know what is slow or fast. Always test it.

Checkout out this link [MySQL profiling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html). Add the index where you think it will work and then run some tests.